# MySQLI crashing on edit of a script that's not linked

Tags: php, .htaccess, mysqli

I have written several scripts for a website and am moving onto the next page of information.

Every time I edit a page the first page crashes.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^timeline(\d+)*$ ./dashboard.php
RewriteRule ^timeline/like/(\d+)*$ ./dashboard.php?action=Like&PostID=$1
RewriteRule ^timeline/dislike/(\d+)*$ ./dashboard.php?action=Dislike&PostID=$1
RewriteRule ^report/(\d+)*$ ./report.php?postID=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?profile=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/edit/(\d+)*$ ./editprofile.php
```

Code for each page:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('core/connection.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
if(!function_exists("isAuthorized")) {
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}
$MM_restrictGoTo = "/login/error/2";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);

  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 

  exit;
} 
}
```

But every time I upload a page that includes this code it crashes the first page. Then if I remove it, it will work.

Any ideas will help.

Comment: Quick comment, adding in the `code`if(!function_exists("isAuthorized")) {`code` it loops the page, to a about 15 lines then will stop and cycle again, and again, and again and again.

Comment: Fixed the bug, for future reference DO NOT use the same file name as the one you're working on.. it'll loop for some reason...